# Event handler in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The below code is working only on Firefox, and not working on IE or Chrome.

```
<form action="advertise2.php" method="get" id="daforma">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('submit', true, true);
document.getElementById('daforma').dispatchEvent(evt);
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you define what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to submit the form as soon as the page loads you could use something like this.

```
<form action="advertise2.php" id="form"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){document.getElementById('form').submit();}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the code you're using is Mozilla-proprietary.

What's wrong with `document.getElementById('daforma').submit();`?

Answer (score 2):

Two things...

**1.)** Use Fiddler to check the media type/mime to make sure you're not declaring UTF. It's one of the many quiet IE bugs.

If serving text/html **do NOT use**...

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

...**instead use**...

```
header('content-type: text/html');
```

**2.)** Internet Explorer has to be told an event is an event.

```
var e = document.createEvent('Event');
if (!e) {e = window.event;}//IE6
```